# How to check one of the element value of list is contained in another list in C# LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have an issue with LINQ. Classes are entities of EF model. I am using C#.

```
List<Employee> collection_1 = ...//dummy data
List<Employee> collection_2 = ...//dummy data
```

I want to check one of the employee in collection_1 is contained in collection_2 using LINQ. How can I check it? Because I am having problem with EF. Just for single value. I can check using contains method. For example

```
db.Employees.Where(x=>x.containes(employee));
```

But I want to check for list just with one sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've got your point :
You check it in either these three ways :

```
Boolean b1 = collection_1.Any(x => collection_2.Contains(x));
```

OR

```
Boolean b2 = collection_1.Intersect(collection_2).Count() > 0;
```

or when employees references are not the same :

```
Boolean b3 = collection_1.Any(x =>collection_2.Select(y=>y.Id).Contains(x.Id));
```

I hope it helps.